# Modal Dialog Jquery UI Blackberry Curve Issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I am creating a Mobile Site using asp.net and i am using JqueryUI Dialog in my application but after implementation its not working on Blackberry Curve but the same code is working on Blackberry Bold. I don't know what might be the issue so please have a look at my code and update me what should i do to get it working on blackberry curve as well...

```
<input type="image" id="imgBtnHelp" src="../Images/Help.png"  onclick="return openPopup();" /> // button

<div id="PnlHelp" class="csPnlHelp" style="display: none;"> // My Div Tag
<uc1:ucHelpControl ID="ucHelpControl1" runat="server" /> // My UserControl
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> // Javascript function
//<![CDATA[
function openPopup() { $('.csPnlHelp').dialog({ width: 460 }); return false; }
//]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I haven't try that out... but today i will try.. let c whether thats works or not... but again on my question its should work on curve but its not working :( ??

Comment: The last mobile site I did, the BBs were notoriously difficult to get the markup correct for display.

Comment: What are the OS versions of the BB devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my 8530 BlackBerry Curve (v5.0.0.1030) the JQuery UI Dialog demo does not work at all. The dialog content is displayed inline with the rest of the page.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

You may just be out of luck. If you need to support this device I would arrange the dialog content so it appears in a reasonable place if jQuery UI is not supported.

Comment: Hey Hat&Beart Thanks for your reply.. yes its not working on Curve... Well I have managed to implement a dialog content which works according to my requirement... Thanks